# How to apply limits for the definite integral $\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos 3x+1}{\cos 2x-1}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> $$
> \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos 3x+1}{\cos 2x-1}dx
> $$

Set $t=\sin x\implies dt=\cos x.dx$
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos 3x+1}{\cos 2x-1}dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{4\cos^3x-3\cos x+1}{-2\sin^2x}dx\\
=-2\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{(1-\sin^2x)\cos x}{\sin^2x}dx+\frac{3}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\csc x\cot x.dx-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\csc^2x.dx\\
=-2\int_0^{1}[t^{-2}-1]dt+\frac{3}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\csc x\cot x.dx-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\csc^2x.dx\\
=-2\Big[\frac{-1}{t}-t\Big]^1_0-\frac{3}{2}\Big[\csc x\Big]_0^{\pi/2}+\frac{1}{2}\Big[\cot x\Big]_0^{\pi/2}
$$

How do I apply the limits here as $t\to0\implies\frac{1}{t}\to\infty$, similarly for $\cot x, \csc x$ etc ?

**Note:** Solution given in my reference1 is $1$

Comment: The function is not continuous at zero (vertical asymptotic line), does the integral converges at all?!

Comment: @ss1729 i upvoted.  interesting question, with good work shown.  what happens if you try to express the entire answer (i.e. all 3 integrals) in terms of $t$, rather than expressing 2 of the integrals in terms of $x$.  i-m too lazy to try that myself.

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3428840/compute-int-0-pi-2-x2-left-sum-n-1-infty-1n-1-cosnx-cosnx

Comment: @user2661923 in either case how do I deal with such situations where substituting the limits give infinity ?

Comment: @ss1729 i was **metacheating** (i.e. hoping that the problem would not have been posed by your teacher if there wasn't a *finite* answer).  my previous comment was intended to suggest an approach where all the **bothersome terms** *might* cancel out.

Comment: @K.K.McDonald My reference gives the solution 1, but not sure about it.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos could you please explain how should we deal with such integrals when it becomes infinity whn the limits are applied ?

Comment: @ss1729 Since it's not convergent (see my answer), it can't be 1. Perhaps you copied the problem wrong or something?

Answer (score 1):

Hint

The numerator can be written as $$\cos3x+\cos x+1-\cos x=2\cos2x\cos x+1-\cos x=2\cos x(\cos2x-1)+1+\cos x$$

Now $$-\dfrac{1+\cos x}{1-\cos2x}=-\left(\dfrac{\cos\dfrac x2}{\sin x}\right)^2$$

Now $$\dfrac{\cos\dfrac x2}{\sin x}=\dfrac{\csc\dfrac x2}2$$

Comment: how do I substitute the limits if it gives infinity ?

Comment: here if you substitute the limits it gives infinity, right ?. My doubt is what do we do in such cases ? and how do we justify that ?

Comment: @ss1729 If you substitute proper limits and get infinity then the answer **is** infinity! I'm not sure why you think that infinity is an invalid answer. That is the expected result since the series is non-convergent in nature.

Answer (score 0):

The integral doesn't converge. Take its negative:
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos(3x)+1}{1-\cos(2x)}\,\mathrm{d}x $$
As $x\to 0^+$, $\cos(3x)+1\to 2$ and $1-\cos(2x)\sim 2x^2$, so $$\frac{\cos(3x)+1}{1-\cos(2x)}\sim\frac{1}{x^2}$$ and it's easy to verify that
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x $$
is not convergent.